# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLVideoElement> has no method 'setSrc'

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm trying to load a video wigh javascript, but its causing error...

The Code:

```
<script src="mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelement/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
<video controls="controls" preload="none" id="dinamic-video">
</video>
<script>
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('dinamic-video');
    $('#btn-play').click(function(){
        player.setSrc('mediaelement/media/teste-html5-MP4.mp4');
    });
</script>
```

The Error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'setSrc'**

How can i run it right?!

---

***--- Edited to place more details about [Ricardus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993097/ricardus)' answer ---***

Does not works...

Nor executed the callback **success** and does not load the video

```
var player;
$(document).ready(function(){
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('video', {
        features: ['playpause', 'progress', 'duration', 'volume'],
        success: function (mediaElement) { 
            console.log(mediaElement);
            var sources =[{ src: "mediaelement/media/teste-html5-MP4.mp4" }];
            mediaElement.pause();
            mediaElement.setSrc(sources); 
            mediaElement.load();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because **setSrc()** is not really a method of your mediaelement object unless you tell javascript that an object should contain all mediaelement methods and properties.
You should first create mediaelement dynamically on **document.ready();** just to be sure.
This is an example:

```
 var player;

    $(document).ready(function() {

    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#dinamic-video', {
        features: ['playpause', 'progress', 'duration', 'volume'],
        success: function (mediaElement) { 

    var sources = [{ src: "mediaelement/media/teste-html5-MP4.mp4" }];
       mediaElement.setSrc(sources); 
       mediaElement.pause();
       mediaElement.load();

         }

    });

});
```

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your help. I try your code, but does not works.

I edited my post with the above result

Comment: Here is a relevant topic of the official mediaelement issues forum:https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/295. You can try this out and tell if successful.

Comment: Hi Ricardus, thanks for the link... Works fine now... I follow the instructions there and voilá!!!

Now the only issue i need to resolve is make support for FLV Videos

Comment: I read your question in the other topic and from your recent comment I figured out that problem solved.

Comment: Its 99% solved! Load MP4/WebM via javascript is working... Load and play FLV onlye using HTML <video> tag is working... but the only thing i can't resolve is load and play FLV files using this javascript implamentation...

Comment: Change this: `var sources = [{ src: "mediaelement/media/teste-html5-MP4.mp4" }];` to `var sources = [{ src: "MYVIDEOPATH.flv", type:'video/flv'}];`

Comment: The first thing i do is make this... does not works. If you can see my post in the github link you previoysly paste here [link](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/295) there are an example with flv that fails

Comment: The issue in that link is closed a year ago. I tried the above code in my answer and it works well on all browsers, except on Chrome, where I noticed it plays the video but not the audio. I suspect it has to do with video encoding.